# react navigation sidebar close issue when quickly click menu

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation (sidebar) in react native project, but when I click quickly on sidebar menu sidebar doesn't close but background scene is changing. In this way I'm navigating to scene. Even the same issue found on kitchen sink app https://nativebase.io/kitchen-sink-app as the I'm following same.
this.props.navigation.navigate(route);

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to generate this issue [here](https://snack.expo.io) ?

Comment: Here is dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6hfbmehzqsscez/levelC.rar?dl=0 of project, the sidebar navigation file exist on this location levelC/src/screens/sidebar/index.js